# Difficulty dealing with empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using the jQuery plugin TagManager.
I am having trouble dealing with empty arrays when the form gets initialized and I cant figure out why. Here is my script;

```
   $(".tm-input").each(function() {
      var e, l;
      e = $(this);
      l = e.data("load");
      e.tagsManager({
        prefilled: $.isEmptyObject(l) ? null : l
      });
    });
```

I set the data attribute `data-load` to the value I want to display.
The `prefilled` option is supposed to get set to null if `l` is empty and it's not working. 
If I break at the `prefilled` line above, the `l` variable value is `Array[0]`.  If I check `$.isEmptyObject(l) ? null : l` it returns null, but the value that gets displayed is `"[]"`.  When the `data-load` value is null it works correctly.

Here is the affected form html;

```
 <input class="tm-input" data-load="[]" placeholder="enter tags here" value="[]" type="text"></input>
```

Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: `l` is likely the string `"[]"`.

Comment: If I set a break, it's value is Array[0].

Comment: Either way, shouldn't the ternary line return null?

Comment: It returns null correctly, because `$.isEmptyObject([]) == true`

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, "[]" ends up as the value on the form.  I probably wasn't clear on what the problem is.  The problem is it ignores the "$.isEmptyObject(l) ? null : l" for setting the prefilled option and it gets set to "[]".  All other values work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it's an issue with the way the TagsManager plugin handles empty arrays.  It ignores the prefilled option and just displays "[]".

Here's what I did to work around it incase it can help someone else;

```
   $(".tm-input").each(function() {
      var e, l;
      e = $(this);
      l = e.data("load");
      if ($.isEmptyObject(l)) {
        l = null;
        e.val("");
      }
      e.tagsManager({
        prefilled: l
      });
```

This forces the input element value to an empty string if it's an empty array, which TagsManager handles better.

Answer (score 1):

Following change may help you:

```
l = e.data("load") || 1 ;
```

if **l** is undefined, this line automatically assign value **1** to it. You can assign whatever value you want, based on your need.